# React-native The Android Gradle plugin supports only kotlin-android-extensions Gradle plugin version 1.6.20 and higher

Tags: react-native, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

So i've recently updated my expo to `"expo": "^48.0.17"`, and react-native to  `"react-native": "0.71.8"`, which are like the latest versions

now when i run `expo run:android` to build my project and run it on an emulator I get this error message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only kotlin-android-extensions Gradle plugin version 1.6.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':react-native-google-mobile-ads' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
C:\Users\admin\Documents\xulucreatives\backup\K53Learners\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: C:\Users\admin\Documents\xulucreatives\backup\K53Learners\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\run\android\spawnGradleAsync.ts:83:18)
    at assembleAsync (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\run\android\spawnGradleAsync.ts:57:16)
    at actionAsync (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\run\android\runAndroid.ts:143:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only kotlin-android-extensions Gradle plugin version 1.6.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version: project ':react-native-google-mobile-ads' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10
```

The error here says the dependency "react-native-google-mobile-ads" uses kotlin-gradle-plugin version 1.6.10 but your project need a minimun version of 1.6.20. (this file is available in the Android project of your app build.gradle).

I suggest you check if the dependecy is up to date. If it is and your app can't function without it, I would downgrade the project. If your app works without it, remove the dependency.